# Is my current lifestyle of biking, eating well, and spend lots of time at a computer.a healthy one?

Tags: food, health

I think I'm an healthy person. I eat vegetables and fruits everyday (or I try my best to). I also avoid eating meat whenever possible. I ride my bike more than 5 hours a week and I walk 15 minutes everyday to get to work.

The problem is I'm spending a lot of time on computers (for work and at home because I'm a gamer) but I enjoy it as much as practicing sport, and I often feel like I'm getting fat and weak.

Do you think I'm doing something wrong, or is it just my feelings that are wrong?

Comment: When you say you ride your bike for 5 hours, is that at an easy pace or does it get your heart thumping? I' guess I'm really asking if you are getting aerobic exercise for 5 hours? Also, what is your body mass index (BMI)? Another factor that affects me is hours of sunlight (I live in bnorther Scotland and in winter get very little sunlight). Too little can have detrimental effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer whether your feeling "fat and weak" is an objective assessment or a subjective/psychological analysis. Your weekly exercise routine is certainly more fitness-inducing than some of my own clients (as a sports massage & nutritional therapist), but if you are eating more calories than you burn, no matter if those are healthier calorie sources than the average diet's, you will store fat. On the other hand, if you are not eating enough calories to fuel your daily and weekly expenditure/exercise, then you can certainly feel weak.

Improper breathing is one thing that can make an otherwise fit person perceive themselves to be unfit. You might want to ask yourself if you are breathing fully and properly during your exercise (or for that matter, throughout the day) to get the most out of it and to improve health markers overall:

1) "We breathe oxygen into the body from the atmosphere. While this oxygen does not itself contain useable energy, it is the key that unlocks the energy stored in previously-ingested food..."

http://www.answers.com/topic/breathing-during-exercise

2) "Learning to breathe during exercise has benefits such as preventing dizziness during activity, improving athletic performance, and increasing fat burning...."

http://www.military.com/military-fitness/workouts/breathing-during-exercise

And also, if you spend a lot of time hunched over or in otherwise awkward positions for your body while gaming or even while cycling, you may want to think about your posture and the suppleness and flexibility of your spinal muscles. Improper posture affects proper breathing (and all the concomitant issues with exercise and health noted above), and can contribute to a general daily feeling of being less than well or not at one's best:

3) "Bad posture is a modern day health epidemic that is much worse than most people naturally assume... One of the worst types of health problems people experience is a loss of the natural curves of their spine."

http://www.naturalnews.com/030956_posture_health.html

Comment: Thank you Stephanie, that helped me. One of my friends also told me that I was not drinking enough while cycling, which I never really paid attention to as I'm a DH biker, but I'm going to try to pay attention to this, my breathe and my posture, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am once a gamer too so i know what u mean by becoming weak as i feel that when i play hour of games without leaving my computer.

computer screen will give out radiation that cause us to feel that way. When i am playing game in the past i will even feel like i want to vomit.

### http://www.emfbioshield.com/arecrt.html

**Should we protect ourselves from computer and TV screens?

### What if the CRT screen turns out to be one of the main culprits of many afflictions of modem civilisation, such as abnormal general fatigue, neuropsychological disorders, increased absenteeism, loss of productivity, declining ability to concentrate and to memorise, aggression and scholastic problems in prepubescent children, predisposition to dyslexia, and lowered spermatogenesis?**

in this link it also say how the radiation will affect us. there are other better link which u could find how the radiation affect us. So u feeling weak is cause by the radiation from the computer and not the real thing. is better that u take a walk outside after an hour of gaming dont get urself expose to the radiation that much and it will be help.

Comment: I don't believe in that sort of things. During summer I often ride ~7 hours a day so during afternoon it's more like 1 on computer, 2 on the bike (which is more than a small break)

Comment: Maybe it affect me but not you. but radiation will play apart in it. just letting u know.

Comment: Since CRT Screens basically aren't used anymore and LCD-Screens are based on completely different technology I wouldn't worry too much about that. Not that I would have worried otherwise. And if people start telling you that LCD screens have the same effect you can ask yourself: Why should they?